# Gnu Emacs indenting of my typedef

Tags: c, emacs, indentation

Gnu Emacs is insisting on indenting my typedef as follows:

```
typedef enum {
    horizontal,
    vertical,
}
    shapes;
```

I want it to indent as follows:

```
typedef enum {
    horizontal,
    vertical,
}
shapes;
```

What switch can I use to get that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the line that "shapes" is on, and hit C-c C-o.  Then press 0 (as that's the offset you want).  Then press Enter.  Then press tab to indent.  Done.

The docs are pretty clear about this process:

http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/info2html?(cc-mode.info)Interactive%2520Customization

Comment: You meant to type `C-c C-o RET`.

Comment: Also, your advice doesn't "stick"; the next time he visits that file, or any C file, the indentation will revert to the way he doesn't like.  Therefore, he should put this in `~/.emacs`:

    (add-hook
     'c-mode-hook
     (lambda ()
       (setq c-offsets-alist
             (cons (cons 'topmost-intro-cont 0)
                   (assq-delete-all 'topmost-intro-cont c-offsets-alist)))))

Comment: The idea you are supposed to glean from my commment is "read the manual", not "here's how to solve the one problem you happen to have today".

I don't use cc-mode, and yet I figured out how to do what the OP wanted almost immediately.  It's because I looked in the manual.

Comment: Or, because you knew where to look in the manual. Thanks for your answer.